# Ignore React Hook "React.useEffect" may be executed more than once

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tslint

I have React component that accepts array of pairs in props. Each pair contains:

- index 0: function that will be called every time dependecines change,
- index 1: array of dependencies.

#### Component usage

```
<MyComponent items={[
    [() => console.log('name has changed'), [name]],
    [() => console.log('email or phone has changed'), [email, phone]]
]} />
```

#### Component implementation

```
const MyComponents = ({ items }) => {

    for (const [func, deps] of items) {
        React.useEffect(() => {
            func() // Everytime dependecies change call function
        }, deps)
    }

    return <div>...Content (not important)...</div>
}
```

I know that count or order of hooks should not change, however `items` will be same during whole component's lifecycle. But still error appears:

> React Hook "React.useEffect" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop.

Is there any way to turn off this error only in this component, without changing tsconfig or tslint? I tried to write `// @ts-ignore` on each line of hook, but it didn't help.

Comment: What situation do you have that requires dynamic amount of effects?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but you can create a component for each item and use effect there

---

```
const SingleComponent = ({func, deps}) => {
  useEffect(()=> func(), [func, deps]);
  return null
 }

const MyComponents = ({ items }) => 
      <>
      <div>...Content (not important)...</div>
      { items.map(([func, deps], index) => <SingleComponent func={func} deps={deps} key={index}/> }
      </>
```

Comment: Use index as key: `items.map(([func, deps],index)=> <SingleComponent key={index}`